# .Net Core 2.1 React and Signalr 1.0.4 throwing a /negotiate 404 error

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-signalr

I am currently working with React and SignalR. I am using .Net Core 2.1 and the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App package to get the recent SignalR. I have installed @aspnet/signalr as well and I keep getting a 404 error because it is still attempting to go to the /negotiate endpoint which I know it doesn't use anymore. I have confirmed I am up to date on on all packages. Any pointers on where I should be going?

```
    const hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('http://localhost:3000/ChatHub').build();

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            //{
            //    builder
            //        .AllowAnyMethod()
            //        .AllowAnyHeader()
            //        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
            //}));

            services.AddSignalR();
            //services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            //app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseFileServer();

            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/ChatHub");
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            //app.UseMvc(routes =>
            //{
            //    routes.MapRoute(
            //        name: "default",
            //        template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            //});

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I keep getting a 404 error because it is still attempting to go to the /negotiate endpoint which I know it doesn't use anymore

ASP.NET Core SignalR definitely still uses the `/negotiate` endpoint. In the previews, we used an `OPTIONS` request instead but that caused a lot of problems so we went back to the `/negotiate` endpoint.

It looks like you're using a "development server" (`spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer` in your Startup). That usually means that the development server is serving up your HTML/JS content from a *different server* than your ASP.NET Core app is running on (rather than just being static files served by the ASP.NET Core app). If that's the case, you need to reference the ASP.NET Core server using a full URL when you connect.

This is because your HTML/JS content is being served by the development server at `http://localhost:X` but your ASP.NET Core server is running at `http://localhost:Y`. So when you use `/ChatHub` as a URL, the browser interprets that as `http://localhost:X/ChatHub`, so you aren't hitting your ASP.NET Core app (with the SignalR server) but rather then dev server, which has no content at that URL and produces a 404.

Comment: No problem! It's a surprisingly common problem, so don't feel bad!

Comment: @AndrewStanton-Nurse hi , I am also facing the same issue . In my case my .net core Angular app is hosted in "http://localhost:xxxx" but my .NET Core api with signal R hub is in "http://localhost:yyyy/checkstatus" both of them are in IIS . So What changes are required to call the signal r api from the .NET Core app using `.WithUrl()` of the Hubconnection in angular client side? Do I have to change the Startup file for `AddSignalR()` middleware ? What should be the api url for `HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl()` in this case

Comment: You don't need to change the server. You just need to make sure your **client-side** code is using the full URL to the server, instead of a relative URL. If you hub is at `https://localhost:yyyy/checkstatus`, then you would use `https://localhost:yyyy/checkstatus` as the url in `.withUrl`

Comment: @AndrewStanton-Nurse: I am using out of the box settings, no full URLs on the front end. I am using React dev server as well. My Web API is listening on `localhost:5001/api`, my hub at `localhost:5001/api/myHub` and I see a POST request to `localhost:5001/api/myHub/negotiate`, but nevertheless the response is 404.